# Change the icon of Git Bash on taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, git, mingw

In Windows 7, after installing Git Bash (1.8.3), I have a shortcut for it with the nice Git icon. However when I open it, the corresponding window doesn't have that icon, just some generic one:

[image: MinGW Git icon Win7]

(same when I `Alt`-`Tab` to toggle between windows).
This was not happening in WinXP - the program correctly had the Git Bash icon.

This seems to be a duplicate of [git bash icon on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/561614/git-bash-icon-on-windows-7) but I didn't manage to make it work with both suggestions put there (rebuilding icon cache, recreating the shortcut).

My shortcut is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: There's no need to put "solved" in the question title - but feel free to accept your own answer (I think there's a time delay of a few hours before you can do this).

Comment: It's a time delay of 2 days that's why I put solved temporarily ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the reason was apparently whitespace in the icon's path. I copied the icon to a directory without whitespace in the path and it works now.